# Orderby to order linq expression in specific order for looking single column

Tags: c#, linq

I have this orderby issue where i need to order the linq expression based on column values. The code goes like this.

```
JsonResult resultCombined = new JsonResult();
List<String> preferences = new List<String> { "E", "M", "H"};
var listCounties = sc.Districts(null, null);
var listSchools = sc.Schools(s => s.YEAR == "2015");

var result = listCounties.Join(listSchools, 
    i1 => i1.LEA, 
    i2 => i2.LEA, 
    (i1, i2) => new { i1, i2 })
.OrderBy(i3=>i3.i2.SCHOOLCODE)
.ThenBy(i3 => i3.i2.SCHOOLNAME);

resultCombined.Data = result;
return resultCombined;
```

Here my issue is I need to order result based on preference order where SCHOOLCODE containes the preference. Simply ordering SCHOOLCODE won't give me the order that I require. Please help me with some suggestion or code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to first filter the records, then apply sorting.

```
var result = listCounties.Join(listSchools, 
    i1 => i1.LEA, 
    i2 => i2.LEA, 
    (i1, i2) => new { i1, i2 })
.Where(i3=>i3.i2.SCHOOLCODE.Contains(preference)
.OrderBy(i3=>i3.i2.SCHOOLCODE)
.ThenBy(i3 => i3.i2.SCHOOLNAME);
```